# GestureDetector allow to pass event to child

Tags: flutter

I have a `WebView` wrapped in a `GestureDetector` like below.

```
GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (dragEndDetails) {
        if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
          // Something happens
        } else if (dragEndDetails.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
          // Something else happens
        }
      },
      child: Center(
        child: WebView(
            initialUrl: "example.com",
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                // Whatever
            },
        );,
      ),
    )
```

Is there a way so that events in both the `GestureDetector` and the child will be triggered instead of in the `GestureDetector` only ?

For instance, if I remove the `onHorizontalDragEnd` handler, the user can resize an image in the underlying `webView` but that's not the case if the handler is present.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a code example.